# Gradle's "assemble -x test" in Groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a custom task `assemble` in groovy which somehow runs tests. I couldn't find out where the tests are executed, but if I run `assemble -x test`, the tests aren't executed. And that's how it should be.

What is the `-x test` equivalent in Groovy? Can I somehow create an alias which replaces `assemble` with `assemble -x test`?

I already tried

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(assemble)) {
        test.enabled = false
    }
}
```

and

```
assemble.dependsOn.remove(test)
```

Both didn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the java plugin diagram [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N16D9D) you'll see that `assemble` does NOT depend on `check` or `test` tasks so I'm guessing something in your build is adding the dependency

[image]

I suggest you add the [task tree plugin](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) to your `build.gradle` eg:

```
plugins {
    id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "1.3"
}
```

You could then do the following at command line to understand where the task dependency is coming from.

```
> gradle assemble taskTree
```

It should look like this

```
:assemble
\--- :jar
     \--- :classes
          +--- :compileJava
          \--- :processResources
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With this tool I was able to find where the test got executed. Somewhere deep down in the tree a task depended on build, which of course executed the tests.

Comment: yup, task tree plugin is awesome... I wish this was a part of gradle similar to the [dependencyInsight report](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#dependencyInsightReport)

Comment: I had this problem too. By mistake I was building as well as assembling in the same command which executed the tests too. It was a bad facepalm moment lol